# Making a POST request with jQuery+HTML to display JSON data

Tags: javascript, python

I want to display json data on frontend but after post request though it is successful it's giving specific data I need to generalize the code.This is python code.

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

def post(url, payload):
    returnData={}

    if url == 'http://api/my-general-api':
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
    else:
        r = requests.get(url)

    #r = requests.get()
    if r.status_code == 200:
        returnData["status"] = "SUCCESS"
        returnData["result"] = json.loads(r.text)
    else:
        returnData["status"] = "ERROR"

    return returnData

def processSingleHost(perfid, hostname, iteration):
    hostsData = {}
    payload = {
        "perfid" : perfid,
        "section" : {
            "hostname" : hostname,
            "iteration" : iteration,
            "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"
            }
    }
    returnData = post('http://api/my-general-api', payload)
    payload = {
                "perfid" : perfid,
                "section" : {
                    "hostname" : hostname,
                    "iteration" : iteration,
                    "sectionname" : "sysstat_x_1sec"
                    }
            }
    returnData1 = post('http://api/my-general-api', payload)
    return {
        "status" : "SUCCESS",
        "sysstat_M" : returnData,
        "sysstat_x_1sec" : returnData1
    }

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #user inputs
        value1 = request.form.get('perfid')
        value2 = request.form.get('hostname')
        value3 = request.form.get('iteration')
        #api call 
        url1 = 'http://api/my-general-api'/{0}'.format(value1)
        payload= {}
        rdata = post(url1,payload)
        hostsData = {}
        if rdata["status"] == "SUCCESS":
            for item in rdata["result"]:
                for host in item["hosts"]:
                    hostsData[host["hostname"]] = processSingleHost(value1,host["hostname"], 1)       //here hostname contain specific value for specific host
        else:
            return "";

        return jsonify(hostname=hostsData);   // returning all host values 

    return render_template('index.html')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my `.js` file for accessing data :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");


  $('form').on('submit', function() { 

    console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

    // grab values
    valueOne = $('input[name="perfid"]').val();
    valueTwo = $('input[name="hostname"]').val();
    valueThree = $('input[name="iteration"]').val();


    console.log(valueOne)
    console.log(valueTwo)
    console.log(valueThree)



    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      dataType:'json',
      data : { 'perfid': valueOne,'hostname': valueTwo,'iteration': valueThree},
      success: function(data) {



        var x = parseInt(data.hostname.sysstat_M.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.AVG); //here hostname is variable I am planning to use that will help to generalize access.

        if(x>80)
            {

                var p = '<p><div class="isa_warning"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i>CPU may be overloading.</div></p>';

                $('#result').append(p);

            }
        else
            {
                var p = '<div class="isa_success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>CPU Usage is Normal.</div><p></p>';
                $('#result').append(p);
            }


      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });

  });

});

$('input[type="reset"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#result').empty();
})
```

But as screenshot showing it demands me to make access specifically by giving `hostname = 10.161.146.94/10.161.146.90`

As mention in above `.js`

```
var x = parseInt(data.hostname.10.161.146.94/10.161.146.90.sysstat_M.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.AVG);
```

But in future this hostname will be different.So I need to generalize it what can I do please suggest ??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SideNote:
If you are using `hostname` or `IPs` to identify each client its not adviced; since it is ought to fail.*

You must use [sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions) for that.

Anyways, if your simply looking for how you can modify your javascript code to access the JSON response when you are not aware of the keys:

```
for(key in data){
    console.log(key);
    console.dir(data[key]);
}
```

Edit:

Showing in select box using jQuery can be done as:

```
var options = "";
for (key in data) {
    options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>';
}
$("#my_dropdown").html(options);
```

Comment: By using this I am able to show it in console.But I am interested in showing only host name as drop down list in second filed as shown in screenshot.

Comment: var x =parseInt(key.sysstat_M.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.AVG);          I now want to display it on screen,what I was trying that "key" contain hostname as 10.161.146.94/10.161.146.90 so var x = =parseInt(10.161.146.94/10.161.146.90.sysstat_M.result.sectoutput.sum   marystats.Avg.AVG);  subsitute key as above and display the content store inside it..but unfortunately  this is not working.What can be done to make this work..if u can suggest

Comment: I got the solution for it. :)